# Confuse While Selecting Book for Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am beginner in Spring Framework , I want to learn Spring with Hibernate; I am confuse in choosing book , I mean which book should I refer Spring 3 (http://www.sharanamshah.com/index.php/books/books-2/books-5/spring-3) or Spring 3 With Hibernate 4 (http://www.sharanamshah.com/index.php/books/books-2/books-6/spring-3-with-hibernate-4-project-for-professionals) .

I want any from above 2 only, because in this book examples are given with IDE;  If there is any book which include Eclipse IDE I am ok with that ... please help me !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is very well documented. Read [Spring Framework Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), and take a look at [Spring Data Project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/).